# TabView inside fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, tabview

I want to make tabView inside a fragment. I have template from [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) and I want to place tabView inside one fragment. Can I implement this like implementation using activity? Any tutorial or advice about this case? Thank you.

Comment: you can use Tabhost Fragment

Comment: I found this [link](https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments) is the closest way to make tabView
I want to make this tabview inside a fragment from NavigationDrawer. I can’t use your MainActivity.java inside my MyFragment.java, since his MainActivity extends FragmentActivity and my MyFragment extends Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) 
(see http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add the tabs inside fragment:

1. TabLayout: Using this layout you can add tab in your fragment and also latest approach provided by android.
2. Tabhost- Using old tabhost layout. This approach is a depreciated approach. However it will also work with fragment properly.

For more reference you can check my example on [GitHub-Material Navigation](https://github.com/eeshan-jamal/Material-Navigation-Combo)

Comment: I found this is the best example [link](https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/) but in that case, he use Activity and extends FragmentActivity. Mine is using fragment and extends Fragment. How can I use MainActivity class in my fragment class?